# Error: Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat when run django on apache

Tags: django, apache, django-templates, django-views

i have a problem when run django on apache:

htdocs/blog/apps/homepage/urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', 'index', name="h_index"),
url(r'^about/$', 'about', name="h_about"),
url(r'^contact/$', 'contact', name="h_contact"),
url(r'^archive/$', 'archive', name="h_archive"),
```

htdocs/blog/urls.py

```
(r'^', include('apps.homepage.urls')),
```

django.wsgi:

```
import os
import os.path
import sys

sys.path.append('D:/Coding/xampp/htdocs')
sys.path.append('D:/Coding/xampp/htdocs/blog')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'blog.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

httpd.conf:

```
Alias /static/ "D:/Coding/xampp/htdocs/blog/static/"
WSGIScriptAlias /blog/ "D:/Coding/xampp/htdocs/blog/django.wsgi"
```

when i run "localhost/blog", it's working. But run "localhost/blog/about/" or other, it's error:

```
[error] [client ::1] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat:   .../htdocs/blog/django.wsgiabout, referer: http://localhost/blog/
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please notice how your apache configuration doesn't match the documented syntax for mod_wsgi's WSGIScriptAlias.

`WSGIScriptAlias /blog/ "D:/Coding/xampp/htdocs/blog/django.wsgi"`

should be:

`WSGIScriptAlias /blog "D:/Coding/xampp/htdocs/blog/django.wsgi"`

(notice no trailing slash after the 2nd token, "/blog")

I just resolved the same issue just now and found this thread Googling. Hope this helps you and future users.

For more information:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango
- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines

Answer (score -2):

I would suspect you are not loading the wsgi module. If you look closely at your error message Apache is treating it like a file and adding about to the name of the wsgi script file it looks for - thus it doesn't find it.

Comment: wsgi module? LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so